# Spring webflow 2 - url mapping not working

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, url-mapping, spring-webflow-2

I'm using spring mvc 3 along with webflow 2. I have been following online resources and have been trying to get an example working. I am unable to get the webflow url mappings to work. It is only the webflow that is not working, the mvc part is working fine.

The error I keep getting is:
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Project2Admin/pizza] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

I have pasted my servlet-context.xml below.

Your help is much appreciated!
Odie

---

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven/>  

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.project2.admin" />




<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>


<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <flow:flow-location-pattern value="*-flow.xml"/>  
</flow:flow-registry>


<beans:bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="com.example.PizzaFlowActions" id="pizzaFlowActions"/>


</beans:beans>
```

---

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

version of servlet_context.html with only one view resolver (jstl view reolver). Both the mvc and webflow parts did not work with this setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven/>  

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.project2.admin" />




<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>


<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <flow:flow-location-pattern value="*-flow.xml"/>  
</flow:flow-registry>


<beans:bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="com.example.PizzaFlowActions" id="pizzaFlowActions"/>


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you please show your web.xml file?

Comment: Hi Japan Trivedi, Thank you for  your response. I have now pasted my web.xml as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your `FlowHandlerMapping` to

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="-1" />
</beans:bean>
```

You are using the annotation driven configuration for Spring MVC which registers a default `HandlerMapping` for you, and I suspect it doesn't fall through to the next HandlerMapping. This has previously been reported as an [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6581). You want the WebFlow `FlowHandlerMapping` to come first - so you set the order to -1. This is what we have in our configs.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by creating a dispatcher servlet for webflows. I'm not sure this is the ideal solution, but it works. Both mvc and webflows are now working fine.

If someone knows a more graceful way to handle this.. i.e. use only one dispatcher servlet to handle mvc and webflow calls, please post an answer, your help would be much appreciated.

thanks!

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>flowServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/flow-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flowServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flow/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

flow-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<!-- Executes flows: the entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->

<!--<start id="flow_executor"/>--> 
<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />
<!--<end id="flow_executor"/>--> 

<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
<!--<start id="flow_registry"/>--> 
<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
<flow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</flow:flow-registry>

<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator"/>
<!--<end id="flow_registry"/>--> 

<!--<start id="mvcFactoryCreator"/>--> 
<bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
<property name="defaultViewSuffix" value=".jspx" />   
</bean>
<!--<end id="mvcFactoryCreator"/>-->  

<!--Maps request paths to flows in the flowRegistry-->
<!--<start id="flowHandlerMapping"/>--> 
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
<property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
</bean>
<!--<end id="flowHandlerMapping"/>--> 

<!--
Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations
-->
<!--<start id="flowHandlerAdapter"/>--> 
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
<property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>
<!--<end id="flowHandlerAdapter"/>--> 

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with two different view resolvers in your servlet-context.xml file.

Please remove the **InternalResourceViewResolver** and put the viewClass, prefix and suffix properties in the **TilesViewResolver** bean.

According to me this should solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Trivedi, Thanks for your response. I followed your advice.. see my new servlet-context.xml above. This did not solve the issue. The webflows are not working. The mvc part of it which was working before is not working now..  I think this is because the InternalResourceViewResolver is needed for views given by @controller annotated classes that I have. Thanks for your help anyways. Odie.

Answer (score 0):

everything is working fine for me with both WebFlow and Spring MVC

here is part of my my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>web-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and my web-dispatcher:

```
<bean id="viewNameTranslator" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator" />

<bean id="basicViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" >
    <property name="basename" value="views"/> 
</bean>

<!-- Resolves logical view names returned by Controllers to Tiles; a view name to resolve is treated as the name of a tiles definition -->
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configures the Tiles layout system -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/views.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/views.xml</value>
            <!-- Flow views -->
            <value>/WEB-INF/flows/**/views.xml</value>              
            <!-- PUBLIC Pages -->
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/public/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

hope this helps